# Google Maps SDK heatmap wont update upon array append

Tags: google-maps, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

**EDIT: Look at my comment in the solution to see what I changed in the updateUIView.**

I am trying to update a heatmap I have on my map via a button press.

Here is how the screen looks:

[GIF of how the screen and interaction look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8adT.gif)

I have the array that the Map uses set to an @Binding variable and the array itself is initialized as an @State variable. The original preset values (as can be seen in the code below) appear on the map but the modified coordinate does not.

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMaps
import GoogleMapsUtils

struct GoogleMapsViewContainer: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    @State var heatmapWeightedData: [GMUWeightedLatLng] = [
        GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20), intensity: 1),
        GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.8623, longitude: 151.2003), intensity: 3),
        GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.8635, longitude: 151.2010), intensity: 3),
        GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.8587, longitude: 151.1970), intensity: 3),
        GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.8579, longitude: 151.1987), intensity: 5)
    ]

    @Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Done") {
                    dismiss()
                }
                .padding(.top, 45.0)
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 30.0)
            ZStack {
                GoogleMapsView(heatmapWeightedData: $heatmapWeightedData)
                VStack {
                    Spacer()

                    Button(action: addTrashLocation) {
                        Text("Mark Trash in My Area")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .stroke(/@START_MENU_TOKEN@/Color(hue: 0.373, saturation: 0.717, brightness: 0.466)/@END_MENU_TOKEN@/, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
                    .background(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50.0)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, -30)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }

    func addTrashLocation() {
        self.heatmapWeightedData.append(GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.8606, longitude: 151.2011), intensity: 5))
    }
}
```

This below is the GoogleMapsView function the above is referencing.

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMaps
import GoogleMapsUtils

struct GoogleMapsView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var marker: GMSMarker = GMSMarker()

    @Binding var heatmapWeightedData: [GMUWeightedLatLng]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude, zoom: 15)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

        let heatmapLayer = GMUHeatmapTileLayer()
        heatmapLayer.radius = 150
        heatmapLayer.weightedData = heatmapWeightedData
        heatmapLayer.map = mapView

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<GoogleMapsView>) {
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude)
        marker.title = "My location"
        marker.map = mapView

        let heatmapLayer = GMUHeatmapTileLayer()
        heatmapLayer.radius = 150
        heatmapLayer.weightedData = heatmapWeightedData
        heatmapLayer.map = mapView

        mapView.animate(toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20))
    }

}
```

In order to be able to use the Google Maps SDK in SwiftUI, I went through a lot of trouble messing around with UIViewRepresentable and an AI since the internet couldn't help me with my answers. This situation has led me to many problems and I would not be surprised if this is somehow not working due to some nuance in the UIViewRepresentable I am unaware of.

How do I get the map to update the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@StateObject` to initialize `ObservableObject`s

```
@StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
```

Then use `@ObserveObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` to pass around.

```
@ObservedObject var locationManager : LocationManager
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Every time you call `LocationManager()` you are creating a different instance. One does not know about the other.

Comment: Thanks. I had done this already in another part of the app that initializes the locationManager (Sorry, my fault for not including that).

Matter of fact, I managed to update it by making it so that the updateUIView function in GoogleMapsView updates when the button modifies the array. All I had to do was copy the 4 heatmapLayer lines from the makeUIView function.